# How do I convert a AT-09/CC2540 BLE module onto my own PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, integrated-circuit, bluetooth-low-energy

Do I need to take the entire AT-09 module or can I just solder on the CC2540 module? Also, what is the plastic cover on the AT-09 for (I'm guessing signal interference)? Is it necessary to have? I would like to just use the CC2540 due to costs and space on the PCB. Any suggestions/pointers?

Comment: From a cursory glance the extra components on the AT-09 look like power-supply circuitry.  My guess is that the CC2540 runs at 3.3V or lower (check its datasheet).  The heatshrink may be related to this (e.g. it may be very easy to fry the module with over-voltage).

Comment: A link to the manufacturer and datasheet of this module would be helpful if not necessary for others to help with your problem. I tried a quick google and found numerous links but nothing that seemed very official.